# How to restore the initial state of <ul>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some  list like this:

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

I want to be capable to restore that list after some manipulation in future, so I save that:

```js
let ul_list = document.getElementById('list');
let items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let li_items = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let text = document.createTextNode(items[i].innerHTML);
        li_items.push(li.appendChild(text));
    }
```

and I create function to restore:

```js
function restoreList(){
    while (ul_list.firstChild) {
        ul_list.removeChild(ul_list.firstChild)
    };

    for (var i = 0 ; i < li_items.length; i++) {
        ul_list.appendChild(li_items[i])
    };
}
```

But using this function I don't get marked list, only three words in a row:

> FirstSecondThird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you write:

```
li_items.push(li.appendChild(text));
```

you are pushing to the array `li_items` the **return value** of the `appendChild(text)` function.

From the [`appendChild()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#return_value):

> ###### Return value
>
> **A Node that is the appended child** (aChild), except when
> aChild is a DocumentFragment, in which case the empty DocumentFragment
> is returned.

So, what you are really pushing to the array (and afterwards inserting again inside `<ul>`) is not the whole `<li>` element but only the `textNode`.

Simply change your loop to:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = items[i].innerHTML;
    li_items.push(li);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem are when creating the DOM, right in the `li_items.push` you shouldn't put the append child inside the `.push`, because it will return [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#return_value).

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let text = document.createTextNode(items[i].innerHTML);
    li.appendChild(text)
    li_items.push(li);
}
```